# I want return to JSON

Tags: python, json, django

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

It is `UserProfile` class.

`UserProfile` model extends `AbstractUser`.

```
def get_rank(request):
    users1 = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    # below code works but variable 'users1' don't work.
    # I want users to JSON. ex) users
    users = '[{"item":"NEFUS"},{"item":"Layer7"},{"item":"Unifox"},{"item":"Focus"},{"item":"Frs"}]'
    return HttpResponse(users , content_type='application/json')
```

This code doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Teh variable `users` works. but variable `user1` doesn't work.

```
function ajax_get_rank() {
    var temp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    temp.open("GET","/get_rank/");
    temp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (temp.readyState === 4 && temp.status === 200) {
            get_rank(temp.responseText);
        }
    }
    temp.send();
}
```

This is the AJAX code.

```
function get_rank(rank_array_temp) {
    var temp = JSON.parse(rank_array_temp);
    for( var i = 0 ; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var div_temp = document.createElement("div");
        div_temp.className = "rank"
        var out = "";
        out += "\
            <div class = 'rank'>\
                <span class = 'grade'>\
                    <span>"+parseInt(i+1)+".</span>\
                </span>\
                <span class = 'item_name'>\
                    <span>"+temp[i].item+"</span>\
                </span>\
            </div>\
        ";

        div_temp.innerHTML = out;
        rank_list.appendChild(div_temp);
    }
}
```

This is the main javascript code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't described what doesn't work. You're passing a hard-coded string; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What does `users1` output look like?

Comment: user1 => [<UserProfile: test>, <UserProfile: a>, etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly serialize django model objects, doing so you would get `TypeError: queryset is not JSON serializable` error.

But you could use `values` to get a collection of fields you want to display then serialize it:

```
profiles = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('created_at') \
                                    .values('field1', 'field2')

users1 = json.dumps(profiles)
```

Note that fields like `DateTime`, `Date` etc, are not json serializable. What you need is:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
users1 = json.dumps(profiles, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: I want to return
{ 0: "Nefus", 1: "Unifox", 2: "Layer7", etc }
or
{ "item": "Nefus", "item": "Unifox", "item": "Layer7", etc }
how to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what are those values in the dictionary in your comment, nor the integers.

Comment: sorry, I don't do well..... plz understand
I want to return
'[{"item":"Unifox"},{"item":"Layer7"},{"item":"Nefus"}, etc]'

Answer (score 0):

Serialize/de-serialize objects directly to JSOn is not a good way practically since:

1. Objects will have problem since they have no descriptor about how to serialize that specific object to JSON
2. Using `values` or `values_list` will have problem when you try to convert special types like `Decimal` since JSON do not have a Decimal type.

Possible solutions:

1. Hard way is creating the list or dictionary in python and then serialize this. You have to parse special types to basic types which are also valid types for JSON data like converting `Decimal` to `float`

   ```
   import json
   height = Decimal("1.78")
   my_dict = {"Name": "Jason", "Age": 16, height: float(height)}
   json.loads(my_dict)
   ```

Or as @ShangWang mentioned, you can use `DjangoJSONEncoder` to encode python specific types without getting errors.

2. Use [Django serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/) for serialize/deserialize. you can specialize which fields wiill be serialized.

   ```
   from django.core import serializers
   data = serializers.serialize("json", SomeModel.objects.all())

   data = serializers.serialize('json', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
   ```

Django serializers is easier to use since they will serialize any valid python type to proper JSON type.

Output of the django serializer will be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "pk": "4b678b301dfd8a4e0dad910de3ae245b",
        "model": "sessions.session",
        "fields": {
            "expire_date": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

So you can get fields and values from `fields` key of each JSON object. You can check the docs for more information.